# What's the proper way to implement highlight.js in phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, highlight.js

I've used [this](http://qiita.com/darui_kara/items/6c87486a070492f46bf0), and it works but it feels kind of hacky. I've tried copying the `highlight.pack.js` file to `web/static/js` and calling it from a `.html.eex` file but that just gives me an error. I've tried using the CDN (it worked) but that didn't give me the results I wanted. So what's the proper way to implement highlight.js in phoenix v1.2.0. I'm using Earmark v1.0.1 for markdown support if that matters.

Comment: Does this http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets#section-javascript-libraries help at all?  It's hard to tell what you're asking for here--what's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way is to install it via NPM:

```
$ npm install --save highlight.js
```

Note that `--save` will automatically add the latest version of highlight.js to `package.json`, you may also set a specific version there and run `npm install`.
After installing, you can import and use the library in `web/static/app.js`

```
import hljs from "highlight.js"
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

The process is the same for any NPM package you might want to use. Non-JS assets, such as CSS files, are not automatically imported from NPM packages. Therefore, you need to whitelist them in the `npm` section in your `brunch-config.js`.

```
npm: {
  // ... keep the other settings
  styles: {"highlight.js": ['styles/default.css']}
}
```

Obviously, replace `default.css` with the name of [your preferred color scheme](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/tree/master/src/styles). More information on pulling styles from NPM packages can be found [in the Brunch documentation](http://brunch.io/docs/js-modules-npm#including-modules-styles).

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me understand how this works.